# In C: passing and printing variables arguments of a function

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program which uses function with variable number of arguments. An additional task is to print all the arguments of every function call separately. The code is as follows:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<string.h>
int mul(int x,...);
int main()
{
int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,x;
printf("The product of %d is :%d\n",a,mul(1,a));
printf("The product of %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,mul(2,a,b));
printf("The product of %d, %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,c,mul(3,a,b,c));
printf("The product of %d, %d, %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,c,d,mul(4,a,b,c,d));
return 0;
}
int mul(int x,...)
{
    int i,prod=1;
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   
        prod*=va_arg(arglist,int);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   
        printf("The argument is %d\n",va_arg(arglist,int));
    }
    va_end(arglist);
    return prod;
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:-

[image: Output of the above program]

The other piece of code is:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<string.h>
int mul(int x,...);
int main()
{
int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,x;
printf("The product of %d is :%d\n",a,mul(1,a));
printf("The product of %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,mul(2,a,b));
printf("The product of %d, %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,c,mul(3,a,b,c));
printf("The product of %d, %d, %d, %d is :%d\n",a,b,c,d,mul(4,a,b,c,d));
return 0;
}
int mul(int x,...)
{
    int i,prod=1;
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   
        prod*=va_arg(arglist,int);
    }
    printf("\n");
    va_end(arglist);
    va_start(arglist,x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   
        printf("The argument is %d\n",va_arg(arglist,int));
    }
    va_end(arglist);
    return prod;
}
```

The output is as follows:-

[image: second output]

Why is this difference? Any help?

Comment: see Mark Byers answer.. he's right.. in the first example you keep to read some data while there is junk in the stack.. you don't call the va_end..

Comment: Think about it - you *know* that `va_arg` must be responsible, in some way, for "moving" from one argument to the next - since you don't supply the position of the argument you want to read, and you're calling it in a loop. So, how is it meant to know (in your first example) that half the time you *do* want it to advance, and have the time you don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are missing two lines:

```
va_end(arglist);
va_start(arglist,x);
```

This means that after doing the multiplication you are reading past the end of the parameters. The values that are displayed are whatever happened to be on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

va_arg(va_list ap, type) retrieves next argument in the argument list.So in the first code  you are consuming the arguments after one loop . Instead of 2nd code you can use the following code which prints argument and maintains multiplication in a single loop

```
int mul(int x,...)

{
    int i,m,prod=1;
    enter code here
    va_list arglist;
    enter code here
    va_start(arglist, x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {   
        m=va_arg(arglist,int);
        prod*=m
        printf("The argument is %d\n",m);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return prod;
}
```